# Unhandled exception type Java InstantiationException

Tags: java, exception, throw

I am trying to add an exception to my code so that an exception is thrown whenever securityManager returns false:

```
public Appointment(String date,String time) {
    //Secure Object Construction
    if (securityManager(date, time)) {
        this.date=date;
        this.time=time;
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }
    //Invalid Object, Throw Error
    else {
        throw new InstantiationException("Date provided is Invalid");
    }
    return;
```

However when I add this I have a syntax error:

```
Unhandled exception type InstantiationException
```

And the IDE wants to add the line:

```
public Appointment(String date,String time) throws InstantiationException
```

However when I do this, the exception **always** triggers.

How do I reformat the code so the exception only occurs whenever securityManager returns false?

Comment: The exception *doesn't* always triggers. It's just that methods that call it *must always* have a "plan" what to do when it happens. They must *either* catch it *or* declare that they catch it themselves.

Comment: You should not use InstantiationException for this.  That is not its intended use.  [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) is designed expressly for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InstantiationException` is a checked exception. You must handle it, otherwise, the compiler will complain about this exception.

Examples of checked exceptions are `ClassNotFoundException`, `IOException`, `SQLException`, etc.

If you wanna raise the exception in the running time, you can use the unchecked Exception which are subtypes of `Error` and `RuntimeException`. IDE will never ask for handling these exceptions.